# Frequency shift after signal passing through a band pass filter in Python

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency-modulation

I'm trying to simulate frequency demodulation in Python. As a part of this, I'm implementing a band-pass filter with cutoff frequencies at $f_c-2f_m$ and $f_c+2f_m$.

There is frequency shift in the final frequency response after passing through the band-pass filter. Is there any specific reason why?

I'm reading the audio file by using `scipy.io.wavfile.read`; the bandpass filter is given by:

```python
    def band_pass_filter(data, low_cutoff, high_cutoff, fs, order=5):
        nyquist =  10000* 0.5 * fs
        low = low_cutoff / nyquist
        high = high_cutoff / nyquist
        print(low,high)
        b, a = signal.butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
        filtered_data = signal.lfilter(b, a, data)
        w, h = signal.freqz(b, a, fs=fs)
        return filtered_data, w, h, b,a
```

[image: Frequency shift]

Comment: What values are you using for low_cutoff, high_cutoff, and fs? You may be running into precision errors, did you notice that your vertical scale goes to 1e190? What does the red line and blue lines represent?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate actual FM so my values are in MHz region. 

fc = 100e6 # Carrier frequency 
fm = 16e3 # Message frequency 
fs = 10 * (fc - fm)

I'm not aware of precision errors, since I'm very new to this topic. Any advice is appreciated.

Te red line is where my actual response should be plotted.

Comment: I recommend NOT simulating actual carriers when simulating modulations, but simulate everything as its baseband equivalent signal.  You will only then need a sampling rate a little higher than 2(fm+fs) rather than MHz, and the carrier provides no information or value to the simulation.  This may help you: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/71312/fsk-modulation-in-baseband/71315#71315

Answer (score 0):

The OP has clarified that the results are due to attempting to simulate FM broadcast modulation (in the 88 MHz to 108 MHz band) directly using the actual carrier frequencies. I highly recommend NOT simulating actual carriers when simulating modulations, as the actual carrier frequency (which "carries" the phase and amplitude envelope of the modulation) is arbitrary and does nothing of value for the simulation. Instead simulate everything as its baseband equivalent signal. This significantly reduces the sampling rate required and simulation time as well as avoids pitfalls such as what may have occurred here.

An FM channel in the 88 MHz to 108 MHz broadcast band occupies less than 200 KHz (with a lot more than just FM as detailed [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/62894/21048)), which can then be simulated as a complex baseband equivalent signal with a sampling rate of 480 KHz (allowing an extra 20%), while sampling at the 108 MHz carrier directly would require a sampling rate around 260 MHz in comparison (almost 542 times higher!).

Consider the following graphic depicting a modulated waveform, on the left as a spectrum centered around a carrier frequency $F_o$, with its variation in time on a complex IQ plane above showing how in this case both its phase and amplitude is changing with time, relative to the carrier frequency $F_o$. (An FM waveform would look similar except as FM we would only see the phase varying and not the amplitude).  On the right we see the same waveform after we have downconverted it to complex baseband, and we see the same phase and amplitude changing in time relative to the new carrier, which is DC! It really doesn't matter what carrier frequency is actually there as our interest is in the relative value of phase or amplitude to any carrier, so you may as well make it DC and simplify the simulation (and reduce the simulation time!).

[image: FM at carrier vs baseband]

Comment: Since the FM range is from 88M Hz to 108M Hz, my low_cutoff and high_cutoff are in MHz range.

N = len(audio_data)
dt = 1e-3/N
t = np.arange(N)     # time span 1 sec
t = t*dt

df = 1/(N*dt)     # df = 1 Hz
f = np.arange(N) *df    # freq span 1 kHz    
fc = 100e6        # Carrier frequency
fm = 16e3         # Message frequency
fs = 10 * (fc - fm)  

I've multiplied nyquist with 10000 because I was getting the error "ValueError: Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 < Wn < 1".